# Multi-part recipes using Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

What is the most appropriate way to handle multi-part recipes with Schema.org?

For example, a cake recipe that has two parts -- the cake batter and a frosting.

Should the two parts be separate recipe objects?  Should they be grouped, without distinction, under a single recipe object?  Or, is there a way to handle the separate parts under a single recipe (or other schema) object?

Here are a few relevant links:

- [The Schema.org `Recipe` type](http://schema.org/Recipe)
- [Google Developers Recipe Page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/recipes)

Comment: Please share the code that you have developed thus far so we can add value to your effort.

Comment: First Instinct: each recipe has its own URL.  The the main Recipe (cake) has a connection to the sub Recipes (frosting and batter) through its `ListItem.url` where the frosting and batter are included as List Items