# Schema.org for complex or multi-part recipes

Tags: schema.org, recipe, structured-data

I am trying to determine how to mark up a [`Recipe`](http://schema.org/Recipe) in Schema.org where the recipe has multiple sub-recipes.

For example: A Victoria Sponge might have:

```
Set #1: Ingredients, preparation steps, and prep/cook times for the Sponge
Set #2: Ingredients, preparation steps, and prep times for the Filling
Set #3: Ingredients, preparation steps, and prep times for the Icing/Topping
```

I have seen recipe examples where all the ingredients are together in a list and the instructions/steps then attempt to determine which is use at which point, but this is not really satisfactory.

Obvious approaches are: separate recipe components, or perhaps an "array" of ingredients and steps. And, I can see it ought to be possible using a [`HowTo`](http://schema.org/HowTo) structure of steps of sub-recipes, but cannot see how.

I'd really like to see an example that has actually been tried. I am using JSON-LD, but anything that demonstrates a principle would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a link to the question that was asked before?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072431/multi-part-recipes-using-schema-org?rq=1

Comment: I can think of multiple ways how this could be represented. Do you just ask for what’s possible with Schema.org, or do you have a specific consumer in mind which you need to comply with?

Comment: I am really looking for an acceptable way... I don't want to reinvent the wheel, or do something that should perhaps not be permitted. My "consumer" is the general public... I have no specific market to satisfy other than for it to allow clarity and compatibility with the various structured data users (Google, Bing, etc). Whatever is ultimately used is likely to be augmented with Open Graph, etc for FB, Twitter, Pinterest...

Answer (score 2):

If you need to group the ingredients per "sub-recipe", you have to provide multiple `Recipe` items, because the [`recipeIngredient`](http://schema.org/recipeIngredient) property is only defined for the `Recipe` type.

I don’t know if such a model was intended, but it seems to be possible with the specified expected values. It works if you think that a `Recipe` instruction step can be a `Recipe` itself.

#### JSON-LD example

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "recipeInstructions": {
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "itemListElement": [
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "item": {
          "@type": "HowToStep"
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "item": {
          "@type": "HowToSection",
          "steps": {
            "@type": "Recipe"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 3,
        "item": {
          "@type": "HowToStep"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Example explanation

- The main `Recipe` has three instruction steps.
- `ListItem` is used to give each step a `position` (so that the `ItemList` is ordered).
- The first and the last steps are [`HowToStep`](http://schema.org/HowToStep) items. A `HowToStep` is a list that can take [`HowToDirection`](http://schema.org/HowToDirection) and [`HowToTip`](http://schema.org/HowToTip) items as list entries.
- The second step is a [`HowToSection`](http://schema.org/HowToSection) item. `HowToSection` is a "sub-grouping of steps". Its definition gives this example, which seems to fit your case:

  > steps for making a pie crust within a pie recipe

  Now, instead of representing this `HowToSection`’s [`steps`](http://schema.org/steps) again as a list of `HowToStep` items, the sub-recipe is given as `Recipe` item. This is possible because `steps` has `CreativeWork` as expected value, of which `Recipe` is a sub-type.

---

(Note that Google’s SDTT doesn’t recognize the `HowTo` types yet. They were introduced with the current Schema.org [version 3.3](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v3.3), which was released last month.)

Comment: THis is very useful - Thanks for taking the time. The fact that Google doesnt (yet?) support HowTo is not that important... we are primarily looking for a way to store 1000+ recipes in a common format that we can then use as source for: website content, structured data, ingredient search etc. If we have this when we can obviously extract/build out to another standard as the need arises.

Comment: @lePusscat: "yet?": Yes, usually Google’s SDTT recognizes all Schema.org types (even those that they don’t use for any of their features), so it should just be a matter of time until they update the tool to recognize the newly introduced terms.

Comment: Unor, many thanks again. Unfortunately I cannot "Up-vote" your answer as my reputation is below 15.